# Reseting MySql column value each month

Tags: php, mysql, reset

I was wondering if there is any way to reset a value in MySql each month. Like lets say I have a points column and its value for april was 500. When the new month kicks in, I'd like that the MySql (or whatever is needed) to reset that value back to 0, so that each new month that value is 0. What are possible ways to do this? I'm quite new with MySQL and PHP in general so I'm not really sure what to do here? Can someone help me out? Thanks heaps guys!

Best regards

Comment: Use MySQL Events for that.

Comment: @juergend can you give me an example in form of an answer so that I can accept it ? :)  PhiterFernandes not sure what you mean by that?

Comment: you can execute mysql command line update query with a cronjob in linux based server.

Comment: @smozgur can you reply with an answer with an example so that I can see if it works?

Comment: This is a strange requirement.  Smells like very bad design.

Comment: @eggyal yeah without knowing the full specs I'd be more comfortable with storing points in their own table with a datetime, and then just select from points in the current month - which will keep full history as well as give 0 points on month start.

Comment: @eggyal I'm not sure if this is the right way to think about it? But I figured it might be a solution to what I was looking for, so I asked the question :)

Comment: @perkes456: See [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the MySQL event scheduler

```
delimiter //
CREATE EVENT your_event ON SCHEDULE 
       EVERY 1 MONTH
       STARTS '2016-05-01 00:00:00'
       ON COMPLETION PRESERVE ENABLE
    DO
      update your_table set ...;
//
```

Comment: Is this a thing? Does it actually work by simply running that query on MySQL?

Comment: Yes, it is that simple.

Comment: thank you for taking your time! It actually works like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

My SQL Command line for update fieldName field in tableName table in dbName database;

```
mysql -uDBUserName -pDBPassword -e 'UPDATE tableName SET fieldName = 0' dbName
```

cronjob for the first day of every month:

```
* * 1 * *  mysql -uDBUserName -pDBPassword -e 'UPDATE tableName SET fieldName = 0' dbName
```

You might need criteria in the query. This is just a sample.

Comment: One of many ways to skin that cat with `cron`! This one exposes uname/pwd in crontab ... which comes with its bag of security issues.

Comment: Surely it does - when someone hacked your linux server, yes.

Comment: Not just in crontab: command line parameters might be exposed in the process list to other (valid) users of the system...

Comment: I am not saying this is secure - I am saying crontab can do that. in fact command line could be saved in a restricted file then be executed from there for better security. There is a lot of methods to do this as mentioned. And actually my vote for the Event Scheduler below which I never used before. I'll try it and see the benefits myself.

Comment: @smozgur not trying to start a flame war, i was just pointing the obvious. Some past hacks (2013-2015) have been known to hack the crontab of various linux distros. I upvoted because this method can be powerful and semantically rich, if security concerns are well managed.

Comment: @YvesLeBorg, not taken as a war indeed! :) yes, I totally agree about the security and as I said, I really upvoted Event Scheduler below :) Sorry, if I sounded as a fighter :))

Comment: Guys just relax, thanks all for the effort you put in to answer my question. I love you all <3 :D

Comment: We are having fun, @perkes456 :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a trick, I know is not the easy way is useful only if you do not care to keep the old values from past months.

Below is my trick:

- first set the month from 01 -31
- if you prefer you can set and the year to current year if the values update after 12 or 13 months
- but if the values was updated usually after some days or below 12 months its ok

The below trick:

```
$start_date = date('Y-m-01 00:00:00');
$end_date   = date('Y-m-31 23:59:59');
```

call the last update of your last value

```
$result = $db->query("SELECT value, value_update FROM $value_table);
while($message = $result->fetch_assoc()){
$prev_value =$message['value'];
$value_update =$message['value_update'];
}
```

then create a if statement with the last update date of your value at database with the range of month

```
   if($value_update >= $start_date && $value_update <= $end_date) {
$value = $prev_value + $new_value;
    }
  else{
$value = round($prev_value - $prev_value) +$new_value;
  }
```

and at the end update your database

```
$update = mysqli_query($db, "UPDATE ".$value_table." SET value='".$value."'");
```

With this hardly trick when updating your db table with a new value in the same month with your last value then keep the last value + the new value, 
but if for example your last value was at 29 February and now the new value is on 01 March the value on db reset + the new value that's mean (0 + new value).

This trick is usefully if you want to update something like API key calls without cronjob just only if your value was update your db and is not important to keep statistics from every month.